# Problems with express middleware priorities

Tags: node.js, express, routes, http-status-code-404, fs

Okay the problem that I am having now is that my error handler gets called before a function is complete currently I use:

```
function loadRoutes(route_path) {
    fs.readdir(route_path, function(err, files) {
        files.forEach(function (file) {
            var filepath = route_path + '/' + file;
            fs.stat(filepath, function (err, stat) {
                if (stat.isDirectory()) {
                    loadRoutes(filepath);
                } else {
                    console.info('Loading route: ' + file);
                    require(filepath)(app);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}

setTimeout(function() {
    require('./errorhandle');
}, 10);
```

The timeout solution works, but it's not a proper one. If routes take longer than 10ms to load it will break again. (404 blocking all pages that are loaded before it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move that function call to somewhere inside the callback function:

```
fs.readdir(route_path, function(err, files) {
  ...
  // Move the function call to somewhere inside this callback, 
  ...
  fs.stat(filepath, function (err, stat) {
    ...
    // Or inside this callback,
    ...
  });
  ...
  // Or even later inside the first callback.
  ...
})
```

I can't tell exactly when you are trying to call that function, but it should be called somewhere inside one of the callback functions. It's up to you to decide exactly when it needs to be called. This will execute the function at the appropriate time, unlike setTimeout(), which isn't meant to be used this way.

Also, you should require all of your middleware at the beginning of the app, because calls to require are synchronous and blocking.

Comment: Did not answer my question directly, but indeed helped me solve the problem with callback functions.